# Qt error: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libGL.so when searching for -lGL

Tags: qt, qt5

**Qt 5.7.0 GCC 4.9.1**
I created a simple widget project (**no single code written, no settings changed,** only drag a few controls to the form) right after installing Qt and did a test compile. I got error messages:

```
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libGL.so when searching for -lGL
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL
:-1: error: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libGL.so when searching for -lGL 
:-1: error: cannot find -lGL
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I reckon that it was trying to link to the 32 bit OpenGL in my 64 bit machine. /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../libGL.so is indeed located in /usr/lib/libGL. The 64 bit version, I think, is the one in /usr/lib64/libGL. How can I change the linking path so that it will link to the right library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how I solved this problem.

1. `locate libGL.so` and find the right 64 bit version (I used the latest);
2. create a link in the Qt lib path: `ln -s /usr/lib64/libGL.so.352.79 ~/Qt/5.7/gcc_64/lib/libGL.so`

Answer (score 5):

This seems like you are missing libraries needed to compile 32-bit binaries.

Try running:

```
sudo yum install glibc-devel.i686 libgcc.i686 libstdc++-devel.i686
```

Comment: You also need to install " libstdc++-devel.i686" for C++ code. You might want to edit your answer and add that.

Comment: This helped me in completley other issue, should be accepted as answer IMO